# Converting Bitmap to Drawable show nothing

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am converting Bitmap into Drawable using following code.

```
MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(thumbnail);
Drawable drawable = (Drawable)new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

The MemoryCache I have used is from [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) Project and it works fine when I use bitmap but when I convert it to drawable then it shows nothing in place of image.

Please Help

Comment: try this Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

Comment: Try to use hierarchyview to debug it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Drawable drawable = (Drawable)new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

To:

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Note that the `BitmapDrawable(Bitmap bitmap)` constructor has been deprecated ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)) and using the above call apparently ensures it gets set correctly with the right target density.

Comment: This is a great bit of info. Without specifying 'getResources()' as the first argument, I was experiencing inconsistent image sizing across different screen densities. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Found

Actually the problem was with

```
MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(thumbnail);
```